# Javascript::put() or return view('index', compact($data))

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-views

Please look into my controller

```php
    class myController extends Controller
    {
      $markets = Market::all();
      \JavaScript::put([
         'markets' => $markets,
      ]);

      return view('test.index');
    }
```

Using this method, I can get all markets in my angularjs file in `markets` variable.

I saw something like below

```php
    class myController extends Controller
    {
      $markets = Market::all();
      return view('test.index', compact($markets));
    }
```

which one would I prefer? what is the advantages of both? what is the difference of both?

Comment: add angular tag too it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st Method:**
It is useful if you want to define your javascript variable from laravel controller method. Then you can use your variable directly into javascript.

```
console.log(markets);
```

But problem is you can't call a PHP or laravel function on that variable.

**2nd Method:**
It's just regular PHP variable declaration and pass the variable to blade template. You can call any php or laravel function on it. But it is not available in javascript.
If you want to make it available.

```
var markets = "{{ $markets }}";
console.log(markets);
```

Both have their pros and cons.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.